# How can I see images from the "cats_vs_dogs" tensorflow dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

I want to see some images from the "cats_vs_dogs" tensorflow dataset.
Using the following code, I can see the first 9 images in the data set.

```
# Download and prepare the data
tfds.disable_progress_bar()
train_ds, validation_ds, test_ds = tfds.load(
    "cats_vs_dogs", 
    # Reserve 10% for validation (from 50% to 60%) and 10% for test (from 60% to 70%)
    split=["train[:50%]", "train[50%:60%]", "train[60%:70%]"],
    as_supervised=True,  # Include labels
)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for i, (image, label) in enumerate(iterable = train_ds.take(9), start = 0): 
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.title(int(label))
    plt.axis("off")
```

How can I display, for example, the images from 100 to 120?

Answer (score 0):

To get the images from 100 to 120, you can use a combination of [`skip`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset?hl=en#skip) and [`take`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset?hl=en#take). Read more about the available functions of the `tf.data.Dataset`API in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset?hl=en).

```
ds_img_100_to_120 = train_ds.skip(100).take(20)
# display
for i, (image, label) in enumerate(iterable = ds_img_100_to_120, start = 0): 
    ax = plt.subplot(5, 4, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.title(int(label))
    plt.axis("off")
```